# How to Prevent Facebook comments spams on wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook, facebook-comments, spam-prevention

We are running our blog on wordpress and we are using the facebook comments on it, But we have a lot of facebook spam comments like this: [image]

I'm marking the comments as spams but I still see it if I opened the blog from another device or in incognito browser: 
[image]

So my main questions now:

1. How to clear the current spams?
2. How to prevent such facebook spam comments that have urls or mobile phones in the comments?

This is the facebook comments script we are using in our wordpress site:

```html
  echo '<div id="respond" class="comment-respond"><div class="fb-comments" data-href="'. $fbURL .'" data-numposts="15"></div></div><style>#comments .module-header, .mv_hidden_comments{display:none !important;}</style>';
```

Comment: There’s absolutely nothing you can do about this programming-wise; the plugin is a “black box”, you have no access to its internal workings.

Comment: Hi @misorude, is there is any way to clear the blogs individually post by post? I thought marking the comments as a spams would solve it but unfortunately it is not working!!

Comment: You can set up comment moderation to be able to manage the comments in one place, but that’s about it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#moderation

Comment: Thanks @misorude! I will go with the moderation direction for now!